# Nullpointer when creating a minimal json-object

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception, libgdx

Consider the following code:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json;    

public class JSonTest
{
    public final String name = "Test";
    public void save()
    {
        FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("test.json");
        Json json = new Json();

        json.writeObjectStart();
        json.writeValue("name", name);
        json.writeObjectEnd();

        file.writeString(json.toString(), false);
    }
}
```

Now, when I call the save() method I get this very strange nullpointer-exception I simply can't pin down:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeObjectStart(Json.java:589)
>     at com.mySuperSecretProject.JSonTest.save(JSonTest.java:8)

I do not understand how this can even happen. I've done JSON parsing quite often, even in the same project but here this won't work. What am I doing wrong?

I've even looked here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON but the docs do it the same way. I do not understand where that Nullpointer comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've [created](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Json.java#L64) your `Json` instance, but haven't [provided a `Writer`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Json.java#L244).

[The `writer` field is therefore `null` and causes the NPE.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Json.java#L589)

Comment: You're right, thank you. I wonder why that's not covered in the wiki, but alas.